# How to set default store in Magento

Tags: magento2

I am trying to change the default store/website in multiple website projects. When I try to log in to the admin and I typed the wrong admin URL then the user redirects to the store abc I want to redirect the user to the other store instead. Same When I try to create a product the product gets created store abc automatically but it should get created in another store.

I tried to change the default page setting but the 404 page on the admin side served from the same store.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to set store links according to Your store as

> Backend > Stores > Setting > Configuration > Go to General Tab > Web >
> Base URLs

For Default Config you need to set one URL, for Another Store you need to set another URL. You do not use **USE SYSTEM VALUE**.

You have also set some other setting as **Session Validation Setting Set to NO**.

Also you need to set **No to Single-Store Mode under General Setting**.